# Import Polygon Data from geojson files into PostGIS using GeoDjango

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango, django-1.10

Am using GeoDjango with PostGIS as Backend. I have few geojson files with features as following example. GeoDjango has provided information to import shape files and other formats but geojson formats. How do I import these geojson files into DB?

```
  "features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SubName": "X", "SubSubName": "A" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 70.693828, 37.074496 ], [ 70.693828, 37.074496 ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "SubName": "X", "SubSubName": "B" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 70.502913, 27.065997 ],  [ 70.502913, 27.065997 ] ] ] } }
```

I have two core requirements:

1. Load the Subregion polygons on webportal using D3JS Map library
2. When i have a lat-long, find in which polygon does this point exist and get the SubName & SubSubName from the polygon properties.

It would be great, if there is proper documentation on PostGIS usage & import files for GeoDjango.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 8):

Taken from - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/geos/

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
# load from geo-json str
pnt = GEOSGeometry('{ "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 5.000000, 23.000000 ] }')
```

The geojson can be for anything like polygon, multi-polygon, etc.

Comment: This answer is not correct. `GEOSGeometry` is just for storing a geometry, which is only a part of a `Feature`. By simply importing the geometry (here `Point`) into the DB, one would completely loose any properties that were assigned to that feature (here `SubName`and `SubSubName`).